# This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. default

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

I'm trying to learn the source of this warning:

[image]

Is this done under control of the browser, or is this part of the code implemented by the website - Stack Exchange in this case? If it's "Stack Exchange", please read on; otherwise pls let me know & I'll delete the question.

This warning/dialog "pops up" when triggered by what the browser thinks is an accidental "unload" of form data. I think I'm happy to have such a warning, as it seems a reasonable "fail safe" device.

But I have one freaking HUGE problem with it: The default action is `Leave Page`. And with the **twitchy** Mac keyboard (where turning your head and coughing are keyboard "shortcuts"), the `Leave Page` option is executed, and I just lost an hour's work in a text box. :(

If the default option could be changed to `Stay on Page`, this might actually be useful.

Comment: Along these lines are laptop touchpads that are factored calibrated to respond to a pixie's sigh in the next room.

Answer (score 3):

That's a browser-based function, and all Stack Exchange *could* do is change the text of the prompt. See e.g. [this link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-add-the-leave-this-page-stay-on-this-page-popup-to-a-website-when-closing). They're not doing this, which can be observed by comparing the dialog in Safari:

[image]

with the one from Firefox:

[image]

and the one from Chrome:

[image]

But note that Stack Exchange does have a feature which helps here: it [automatically saves drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/295232) of any question or answer you write. Just return to the page and you can continue writing your post. Since drafts are stored server-side (they're tied to your account) you can even start in one browser (e.g. on a mobile device) and finish on another one (e.g. on your laptop).

Comment: I see the `save draft` feature in use frequently. Mostly, "it just works". But sometimes it doesn't - like today. I had a partial answer I had saved and published. Today, I began a major edit on that published answer... ~2 hours work. Then, out of nowhere, comes the dialog (shown above), then something that my Macbook interprets as input, and POOF - 2 hours work is gone bye-bye with no known method of recovery. So yeah - the `save draft` feature works - some of the time.

Comment: Wrt this being a browser-based function, I found some info that said it was a function *supported* by Mozilla, but the developer (SE folks) had to invoke it. That said, I did a search in a SE page here & got no matches for `beforeunload`. I figured it might be "hidden" in a library (?). Are you certain this isn't done by SE?

Comment: Mozilla support said this re who controls presentation of the pop-up: `Websites can set up an event listener on the "beforeunload" event. Firefox displays that standard dialog in that case. Firefox won't display the dialog on its own.` Consequently, I feel that part of your answer is *misleading*. If you'd like to edit your answer, I'll consider accepting, but I can't do that as it is now written. And by all means - if you disagree, please forward something supporting your statement.

Comment: It's probably activated in the `onchange` event of the form elements. I can't tell since the JavaScript is minified, but `window.onbeforeunload` is `null` when loading the edit page and not `null` after doing some editing. Stack Exchange developers will need to tell how it works exactly.

Comment: FWIW: My solution to this ([the occasional failure of SE's autosave feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)) are the Firefox *extensions* named `Form History Control II`, and `Textarea Cache`.